Поиск решения на Python
С клавиатуры задаем число.
Вывести число "50", заданное с клавиатуры число раз
Как написать код, чтобы число "50" выводилось подряд без пробелов заданным числом раз с клавиатуры?

почитайте про print и про цикл for

Решение с использованием возможности умножать строку:
print('50'*int(input()))

Если делать более универсально, можно дополнить:
print(input('Строка: ')*int(input('Число повторений: ')))

